# При нажатии назад приложение закрывается

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть несколько фрагментов. При нажатии на кнопки они заменяются. Но если перейти назад (нажать на стрелку на телефоне), то приложение закрывается, а не переходит на предыдущий фрагмент. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `addToBackStack(null)`:

```
 FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
....
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

`onBackPressed()` в активити:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
    this.finish();
} else {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
}
```

Comment: работает, но фрагменты накладываются друг на друга